# Resolving require('some.json') using NPM rollup

Tags: javascript, node.js, rollupjs

I have a bundle building script using Rollup but inside my code I have a simple JSON "require" import that "rollup" is not resolving for some reason, and there are no errors, anyone is aware of the reason and how to resolve it (it leaves that code alone and just retains the original code without converting it)?

```
const translation = require('../translation.json');
```

My rollup config script "*rollup.config.js*" looks like this:

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';

export default {
    input: 'src/javascript/script.js',
    output: {
        file: 'dist/script.js',
        format: 'iife'
    },
    plugins: [
        resolve(),
        commonjs(),
        replace({
            'process.env.LANG': JSON.stringify(process.env.LANG)
        }),
        json()
    ]
};
```

My original intent was to resolve the require import with a dynamic variable that allows me to construct the file path in the following way:

```
const translation = require(`../translation_${process.env.LANG}.json`);
```

But I cannot even get the the simple require to resolve using Rollup

PS: I can get this to work with webpack but it creates so much code junk that it makes majority of the basic bundled code hard to read or in some cases unreadable, so trying to stay away from it

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: @Christian as mentioned above, everything compiles correctly but the following is just left alone `const translation = require('../translation_${process.env.LANG}.json');`

Comment: @Christian so I find random `required("something.json")` littered in a few places where I need the JSON files imported